# SolidJS & Vitest - No named export called "hydrate"

Tags: solid-js, vitest

I'm new to SolidJS, trying to learn it right now. I come from a mainly React background, and I really like the concepts at work here. Anyway, I'm trying to get vitest to work, I've set things up exactly as examples online have showed, but I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: The requested module 'solid-js/web' does not provide an export named 'hydrate'
```

There's no stack trace sadly, just this error and a line number. The line number points to this:

```
import { App } from './components/App';
```

So basically the error is coming from trying to render my SolidJS component tree. I'm using solid-testing-library to do this.

I'm unsure where this error is coming from.

Comment: No, I mean vitest. This only happens when using vitest, not when running or building the app with vite itself.

Comment: getting the same error and found an issue about it on [solid-testing-library's github](https://github.com/solidjs/solid-testing-library/issues/10) but nothing on vitest's.
I try to find where this error is coming from

Comment: Not sure if it'll be helpful, but here's an article that walks over the steps to setup solid with vitest: https://dev.to/mbarzeev/testing-a-solidjs-component-using-vitest-2h35
But I still would go for jest instead. There are still some unfixed issues.

Comment: works fine for me in the console, but not in wallabyjs